# Body parser's req.body returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I keep getting `undefined` for `req.body`. Why?

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express')(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username)
});
```

*EDIT*: The above snippet is a simplified version, I thought I encompassed everything involved, but it runs fine. Here's the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/dx9kswdy/

Comment: There's an extra `}` on line 11.

Comment: The information provided in the question isn't enough. Could you add the full stack trace for the error message to the question post?

Comment: @gnerkus That's my bad. Have slipped why I was simplifying my issue. Problem is still there

Comment: The `bodyParser` module depends on the `Content-Type` given with the request and only acts on certain values. How is the request prepared? Is it submitted from a `<form>`? Does it specify an `enctype`? Or, is it sent using Ajax/`fetch`? How is the data being formatted?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski It's a form submitted via `POST`. Just 3 fields with the submit `input`, enveloped in a form.

Comment: Add body parse json middleware before bodyparse url encoded  middleware .It was worked on my scenario

Answer (score 0):

print out req only, if it is still undefined than it is not assigned a value when passed into the function. if it returns a JSON file, parse it to an object!

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(req).body.username);
});
```

Comment: It returned an enormous JSON file.

Comment: if it is a json file, turn it into an object in the function before looking for its values

Comment: It's a JSON object - the same

Answer (score 0):

When I started up your example, it logged the username from the body for me

`curl -X POST -d '{"username": "doug"}' -H "content-type: application/json" localhost:3000`

`dougwade npm-experiments/express-undef » node index.js
doug`

What symptom are you getting? Is it an actual error, or are you just logging "undefined"?  If you're just logging undefined, the problem is that the key username isn't found on your (correctly parsed) body.  If you're getting an error, please post the full trace.

Edit: pulled the fiddle and ran it.  Had to remove some relative imports, but your use of body-parser is just fine:

`dougwade npm-experiments/express-undef » node index.js
doug
ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at /Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/index.js:23:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:129:5
    at invokeCallback (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)`

from the request:

`dougwade npm-experiments/express-undef » curl -X POST -d '{"username": "doug"}' -H "content-type: application/json" localhost:3000
ReferenceError: user is not defined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/index.js:23:9<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:129:5<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/Users/doug.wade/npm-experiments/express-undef/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)`

Comment: I simplified the code in order not to confuse potential answerers. Here's the entire thing: https://jsfiddle.net/dx9kswdy/

Comment: This should be a comment since it does not answer the question.

Comment: @gnerkus the question is "why is body undefined"; the answer is "its not"

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a couple times, and here's what it usually ends up being:

When you're making your request with curl/the browser, make sure you set the Content-Type header to `application/json`. That's what triggers Express / the Express body parser to parse the string as JSON.